# Python: Mathematical Sets and Tuples

Tags: python, list, math, set, tuples

I am implementing a method in my python program that checks if a mathematical function is valid.

An example of one in my program would be:

```
['set',['tuple',1,2],['tuple',3,4]]
```

Which equates to, {(1,2),(3,4)}
For the check to return True all tuples within the set must have a unique number as their leftmost value. So the function {(1,2),(1,4)} would return false.

Currently I have implemented this for a set with one tuple, which would require no check for a unique value in the tuple:

```
if "set" in argument:
    print("Found a set")
    print("Next part of argument", argument[1])
    if "tuple" in argument[1]:
        print("Found a tuple, only one found so this argument is a function")
```

I am unsure how to implement this for a set that may contain multiple tuples like the examples above.

Comment: You'd better modify the data struct you want to process , maybe a dictionary like ```{'type':'set','data':[{'type':'tuple','data':(1,2)},{'type':'tuple','data':(3,4)}]}``` or a class or something .

Comment: It looks like a homework assignment, so I'm not gonna write the code for You but i can give some hints: use a `for` loop to iterate through the rest of the list and create a `set` so You can check if the first value in a tuple is already there and therefore it's not unique.

Comment: @TonyBabarino Thanks, I'll give this a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
def is_function(thing):
    if thing[0] == 'set':
        different = len(set(element[1] for element in thing if element[0] == 'tuple'))
        tuples = sum(1 for element in thing if element[0] == 'tuple')
        return different == tuples
```

If the first element is `'set'`, then count the number of different first items in the tuples (by measuring the length of its set), and compare it with the amount of "tuples" in the list.

```
>>> is_function(['set',['tuple',1,2],['tuple',3,4]])
True
>>> is_function(['set',['tuple',1,2],['tuple',1,4]])
False
```

---

#### Better explanation:

1. The function first tests whether the first element of the list is "set", if it's not the function terminates (and returns `None`).
2. A set is created from the generator comprehension `element[1] for element in thing if element[0] == 'tuple'`, which will be the set of all second elements of all those lists in the main list that have a first element called "tuple". This set will contain all first values, each of them once (because it's a set).
3. The cardinality of that set is stored in `different`. It is the amount of different elements directly after `"tuple"`.
4. A sum is calculated from a similar generator comprehension. Again, this iterates over all sublists whose first element is "tuple", but what is added up is just the number 1, therefore the result will be the amount of sublists that start with "tuple".
5. The function returns the result of `different == tuples`; so `True` if they're the same and `False` otherwise. If there are several "tuples" with the same starting element, then `different` will be smaller than `tuples`, so it will return `False`. If there aren't, it will return True, because the number of "tuples" with different starting elements will be the same as the number of "tuples".

Comment: While this does work I am hesitant to accept it since I'm not quite sure what is going on in this method.

Comment: @hezzag I'd be happy to explain it better, if you want me to.

Comment: @hezzag Added a more detailed explanation.